# The differences between .build, .create, and .create! and when should they be used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I've been seeing people using `.build`, `.create`, and `.create!` within their controllers more and more lately. What's the difference from just using `.new` and passing the param'd object and then `.save`? Are there pros and cons? Does using these other methods offer benefits?

Answer (score 253, accepted):

There are a couple differences, but they're not big:

1. `.create` is equivalent to `.new` followed by `.save`. It's just more succinct.
2. `.create!` is equivalent to `.new` followed by `.save!` (throws an error if saving fails). It's also just a wee bit shorter
3. I think `.build` is *mostly* an alias for `.new`.  It [works one way in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954313/build-vs-new-in-rails-3) and another way in Rails < 3.x

The most important part, however, is that these methods can be called through an association (`has_many`, etc.) to automatically link the two models.

Comment: I'm selected this one as the most correct answer because of the mention on being able to link the associated models with them - that's an interesting and important difference I think over using .new and .save. Which takes a little extra work. Thanks.

Comment: Minor clarification on 3 - build does a little more than just new - it also sets the association link.

Comment: How do you call through an association in a Has-Many relationship ?

Comment: Build is different from New. But the difference is not that it sets the association link (New does that too for the new instance). The difference is that Build populates the caller with the new instance, but New doesn't. 

So for example:
Wall.posts.new gives you a new post associated with your Wall, but Wall.posts is still empty after this call.

Wall.posts.build gives you a new post associated with your Wall, and your Wall.posts now has one post in it.

Comment: Isn't it just an alias now, with no special functionality?

Comment: In Rails 4, I just checked in console. wall.posts.new and wall.posts.build are both populating the wall object in exactly same way. Means after wall.posts.new, wall.posts is not empty as claimed in Amin's comment.

Comment: @AminAriana Then what is the difference between `.build` and `.create`? According to the docs, `.save` will also create a new record in the database (populations caller with new instance?). Docs on `.save`: " `If the model is new a record gets created in the database, otherwise the existing record gets updated`"

Answer (score 37):

Although it is correct that `create` calls `new` and then `save` there is a big difference between the two alternatives in their return values.

`Save` returns either `true` or `false` depending on whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not. This can then be used for flow control as per the first example in the question above.

`Create` will return the model regardless of whether the object was saved or not. This has implications for the code above in that the top branch of the `if` statement will always be executed even if the object fails validations and is not saved.

If you use `create` with branching logic you are at risk of silent failures which is not the case if you use `new` + `save`.

`create!` doesn't suffer from the same issue as it raises and exception if the record is invalid.

The `create` alternative can be useful in controllers where `respond_with` is used for API (JSON/XML) responses. In this case the existence of errors on the object will cause the errors to be returned in the response with a status of `unprocessable_entity`, which is exactly what you want from an API.

I would always use the `new` + `save` option for html, especially if you are relying on the return value for flow control.

Answer (score 6):

#create is shorter version of new and save.
#create! is throwing exception if validation was not positive.

Answer (score 5):

I'd second the above answers. Plus for `create`, one cannot pass `false` as an argument which you can do with `save`. Passing `false` as an argument will skip all rails validations