# Rails Recaptcha plugin correctly returns failure, still saves model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, recaptcha, simple-form

I am using [recaptcha](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha) and [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) with a comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry
  attr_accessible :name, :content, :post_id, :parent_id
  belongs_to      :post, :touch => true
end
```

But comments_controller.rb#create will save the comment with or without a correct captcha.

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.create(params[:comment])
  if verify_recaptcha(:model => @comment) && @comment.save
    flash[:notice] = "Replied"
    redirect_to(post_path(:id => @comment.post))
  else
    flash[:error] = "Incorrect word verification. Are you sure you\'re human?"
    redirect_to(post_path(:id => @comment.post))
  end
end
```

Here's the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for :comment, :url => { :controller => :comments, :action => "create" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :post_id, :required => false, :as => :hidden %>
  <%= f.input :parent_id, :required => false, :as => :hidden %>
  <%= f.input :name, :label => false, :placeholder => "Name (optional)", :required => false %>
  <%= f.input :content, :label => false, :placeholder => "Reply", :as => :text %>
  <%= raw recaptcha_tags -%>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Reply" %>
<% end %>
```

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but I think you want:

```
@comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
```

With `Comment.create` your model is already saved before your if/else.

Look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403671/the-differences-between-build-create-and-create-and-when-should-they-be-use/403714#403714).