# Do we need to create associated object in new method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Have a look at the following code from [spree](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/7fb31d3c48ab6f414a3af8c5e929b67c46f5527a/backend/app/controllers/spree/admin/stock_movements_controller.rb)

```
  def new
    @stock_movement = stock_location.stock_movements.build
  end

  def create
    @stock_movement = stock_location.stock_movements.build(stock_movement_params)
    @stock_movement.save
    flash[:success] = flash_message_for(@stock_movement, :successfully_created)
    redirect_to admin_stock_location_stock_movements_path(stock_location)
  end
```

Is it really necessary to build associated object in `new` method

```
@stock_movement = stock_location.stock_movements.build
```

or below line is fine

```
@stock_movement = StockMovement.new
```

Please explain..

Comment: This was the best explanation for me when I had a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403671/the-differences-between-build-create-and-create-and-when-should-they-be-us

Comment: Deleted my answer. @oneWorkingHeadphone is right, that answer explains it better.